# Unable to get customer response in Salesforce whenever we will send email from case record to that web email & it's not matching to the same thredId

Tags: salesforce-service-cloud

Whenever any case is created in Salesforce, Sales rep will send email to that customer from case object's email button. The email will be received by customer but when customer will reply to that email of Sales rep, that email is not getting into Salesforce and it's not attaching to the same thread of email of Sales rep in Salesforce.

What should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the case thread is added to the template that the customer replying

Comment: Such answer should be a comment posted on the question itself or on the answers of others.